# How to get is accent color enabled for title bar and border or not in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Are there a way to get the value of this setting in UWP?

[image: Windows 10 personalization setting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there a way to get the value of this setting in UWP?

The answer is No. Currently, there is no such API that could directly get this value from Windows Settings. You could submit a feature request about this in the Feedback Hub.